# How can I edit Cargo.toml in order to include resource files in my Cargo package?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I want to bundle a word list in plain text format with my Cargo package. Can I edit Cargo.toml in order to do this?

If I used npm, I would add this to my package.json:

```
"files": ["data/my_dictionary.txt"]
```

I tried `include` but it doesn't seem to work.

Here is my Cargo.toml

```
[package]

name = "chamkho"
version = "0.0.2"
authors = ["Vee Satayamas <vsatayamas@gmail.com>"]
test = true
description = "Thai word segmentation/breaking library and command line"
documentation = "https://github.com/veer66/chamkho/blob/master/README.md"
homepage = "https://github.com/veer66/chamkho/"
repository = "https://github.com/veer66/chamkho.git"
readme = "README.md"
keywords = ["text", "nlp", "thai", "library"]
license = "BSD-2-Clause"
include = ["**/*.txt", "**/*.rs","Cargo.toml"]

[[bin]]
name = "wordcut"
path = "src/cli.rs"
```

This is the output of `cargo package -l`

```
Cargo.toml
src/acc.rs
src/cli.rs
src/dict.rs
src/edge.rs
src/graph.rs
src/graph_builder.rs
src/lib.rs
src/space_acc.rs
src/wordcut.rs
tests/wordcut.rs
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe `include = ["data/my_dictionary.txt"]` should work.

(I [opened a PR](https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/pull/1446) adding this to the documentation.)

Comment: When I run "cargo package", it failed to verify package tarball.

Comment: What is the full output of `cargo package`? (Could you edit it and the `Cargo.toml` you are using into the question?)

Comment: I have to commit it to git first.